# Why is my double or int value is always 0 after division?

Tags: c++, division, integer-division

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm experiencing some strange behaviour from a percentage increase method I am writing for some image editing software.

What I want to do is give the R G or B value of the current pixel and divide it by some modifier, then multiply it by the new value to return the percentage increase, fairly easy concept.

However, whenever I run my debugger, the return value is always 0, I thought this may be because I was trying to do operations which give negative numbers on an integer (or maybe a divide by zero could occur?), so I tried to use a double to store the output of the computation, however I've had no luck.

The code I'm struggling with is below:

```
int Sliders::getPercentageIncrease(int currPixel, int newValue, int modifier)
{
    // calculate return value
    double returnVal = (currPixel / modifier) * newValue;

    // Check we are returning a positive integer
    if(returnVal >= 0)
        return (int)returnVal;

    // Return a negative integer value
    return (int)(0 - returnVal);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

NOTE: I have checked values, of inputs in my debugger and I get stuff like:

```
currPixel = 30
newValue = 119
modifier = 200
```

From this I would expect an output of 18 (I am not concerned with returning decimal figures)

Comment: The `currPixel / modifier` expression is integer division, so if `modifier` is larger than `currPixel` then the result will be zero.

Comment: You're assigning the result of dividing `integers` to a double hence 0

Comment: Try changing your integers to doubles. Since your result is a double the result will be false / 0.

Comment: Seems like it is having rounding issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current calculation only involves integers and so will be affected by integer division (which truncates the result to the nearest integer value).

```
(currPixel / modifier) * newValue
     |           |
      ---------------integer division e.g. 10/3 = 3, not 3.333
```

The result is then cast to double, but the accuracy is lost before this point.

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int val1 = 10;
    int val2 = 7;
    int val3 = 9;

    double outval1 = (val1 / val2) * val3;
    double outval2 = ((double)val1 / val2) * val3;
    cout << "without cast: " << outval1 << "\nwith    cast: "<< outval2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
without cast: 9
with    cast: 12.8571
```

<kbd>[See it here](http://ideone.com/ChKaD8)</kbd>

Note that the cast has to be applied in the right place:

```
(double)(val1 / val2) * val3 == 9.0      //casts result of (val1/val2) after integer division
(val1 / val2) * (double)val3 == 9.0      //promotes result of (val1/val2) after integer division
((double)val1 / val2) * val3 == 12.8571  //promotes val2 before division
(val1 / (double)val2) * val3 == 12.8571  //promotes val1 before division
```

Due to promotion of the other operands, if in doubt you can just cast everything and the resulting code will be the same:

```
((double)val1 / (double)val2) * (double)val3 == 12.8571
```

It is a little more verbose though.

Answer (score 2):

Since all three parameters are integer the result of the calculation

```
double returnVal = (currPixel / modifier) * newValue;
```

will always be truncated. Add cast to (double) and the result should be fine. Simply:

```
double returnVal = ((double)currPixel / modifier) * newValue;
```

If you only set a cast before the bracket the result of the division stays an integer.

Comment: Add the cast **before** the division is done. `(double)(1/2)` is still `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all values are in a range, let me say, less than 1000 and greater (or equal) than 0, which is common on colour values, do something like

```
int returnVal = (currPixel * newValue) / modifier
```

No need for doubles; it will even speed up the code.
Needless to say, `modifier`should not be zero.

Comment: well, `(int) ((5.0 * 6.0) / 20.0) == (int) (1.5) == 1` AFAIK. Not much of a difference.

Comment: The existing code rounds the double back to int on return. There might be some direction of rounding differences for negative inputs, though.

Comment: What's lacking here is an exact specification of the behaviour of the function. Should non integer results be rounded or truncated? Since the return value of the function is an int, we'll have an error most of the times. The calculation above doesn't make it worse, is deterministic and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
// calculate return value
double returnVal = (static_cast<double>(currPixel) / modifier) * newValue;
```

Or this:

```
double returnVal = (currPixel / static_cast<double>(modifier)) * newValue;
```

As you know that `operator /` will be performed first, and then the `operator *`. I have typecasted one of the operands of `/` to `double`, and hence division will be performed `double`. Now, left operand of `*` would be `double` (since `/` produced `double`), and the multiplication would be performed `double` also. For clarity and correctness, you may write:

```
double returnVal = (static_cast<double>(currPixel) / static_cast<double>(modifier)) * static_cast<double>(newValue);
```

Or simply:

```
double returnVal = (double(currPixel) / (double)modifier) * (double)newValue;
```

But, following is WRONG:

```
double returnVal = (double)(currPixel / modifier) * /*(double)*/ newValue;
```

Since the division would be performed `int` only! It is like:

```
double x = 10/3;
```

Where you need (either):

```
double x = 10.0/3;
double x = 10/3.0;
double x = (double)10/3;
```

Answer (score 0):

casting to double should fix the error.

```
double returnVal =  (double ) (currPixel) / (modifier) * newValue;
```

see type casting rules  [typecasting rules in c](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm).